# Keyboard Shortcut for Creating a new Desktop (new Space) on MacOS

Tags: macos, desktop, spaces

How do I create a new Desktop ("Space") on macOS using only the keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution with apple script here, credit to @codehearts:
https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst/issues/143

```
tell application "System Events"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
  click button 1 of group "Spaces Bar" of group 1 of group "Mission Control" of process "Dock"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
end tell
```

The script can be either saved as a ...applescript file with #!/usr/bin/osascript line to run in the shell, or bind to a key directly in Alfred to start a new desktop through Mission Control.

-- 2022-08-16 updating my answer for newer mac os, such as Monterey. Thanks to @Peter-May

Comment: Note that in Big Sur the location should be changed to `/System/Applications/Mission\ Control.app`

Comment: Is it somehow possible to get feedback what workspace was created? I would like to change focus to that new worksapce after creation.

I can use:

index="$(yabai -m query --displays --display | jq '.spaces[-1]')"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there are any native solution to this problem, but there are third-party applications that can help.

One of them is BetterTouchTool, a program that can aid operating a Mac in several ways.

Another is Hammerspoon, but that requires you to write some code yourself.

I doubt these are the only two, only the two I know of.

Comment: Have you checked yourself? I have BetterTouchTool but there is only keyboard shortcut option to switch to (already created) desktop but doesn't create new one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **yabai** as a tilling window manager. It has two commands to create and destroy desktop respectively, i.e.

> #Create space on the active display
>
> **yabai -m space --create**
>
> #Delete focused space and focus first space on display
>
> **yabai -m space --destroy**

Then I use **skhd** to bind hotkey with these commands as

> **cmd + alt - n : yabai -m space --create**
>
> **cmd + alt - w : yabai -m space --destroy**

The main page about **yabai** and **skhd** are listed as:

1. [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/wiki/Commands#move-window)
2. [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd)

Comment: This will work only if System Integrity Protection(SIP) is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Ipstone's answer, for BigSur I had to add `quoted form of` and update the location of Mission Control to get it to work.

So my apple script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
  click button 1 of group "Spaces Bar" of group 1 of group "Mission Control" of process "Dock"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
end tell
```

Then I can run it with `osascript create_new_space.scpt` or bind it to a keystroke with skhd.